# Verificar quais sessões Websocket estão inativas

Tags: java-ee, glassfish, websocket

Como verificar se uma sessão está ativa, quando o dispositivo que esteve conectado ao servidor Websocket desligou repentinamente?

Pois nessa situação, se uso o método `Session.isOpen()` o retorno é `true`. Creio que o retorno deveria ser `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `isOpen()` apenas indica o status da conexão conforme o protocolo WebSocket (Ou seja, se um dos lados não fechou a conexão, por exemplo, com o método `close` do lado do servidor).

A questão de verificação de conectividade fica a cargo da sua aplicação. Você pode fazer isso implementando trocas de mensagens `PING` / `PONG` ou com o uso de [Control Frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5) `ping` / `pong` com o exato mesmo propósito (recomendo o caminho pela aplicação pois nem todos os navegadores suportam *Control Frames* muito bem).